# Does ListView has a size limit?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm developing a logging app on my Android, and I'm showing the results on a ListView.

Is there a component limit of how many items I can add to a ListView? I couldn't find this information on the docs...

Comment: Not really @R.T., that post is talking about the actual layout height of the component, not the items count...

Comment: Actually, Like other log information either from any IDE or command prompt or Terminal they just set some  limits over data stored for log information and according to it they displayed occupied data in ListView. May be size something like 512 KB, 1028 KB or any is just defined by you, on how much amount of memory you want to occupied for your application log information. Its all depends on you may be you can write all log information in file and just want to display some portion in Listview..

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listview is virtualized so **it has practically no size limit**. So you dont have any limit to add the number of elements in it.

You may check this a good [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: So, we might state that it's only limited by the device's available memory, on running the app?

Comment: @LcSalazar:- Yes thats true.

Comment: listviews can be configured to dynamically query data as they are scrolled, hence it's a mistake to think the entire data set must reside in memory at any given point.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a HUGE number of records but only a certain amount is going to be shown on the screen..  I'm talking numbers in the billions if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is theoretically no limit to the number of elements in the ListView. The only limit is the memory of the phone. But since ListView has some clever mechanisms for saving memory, you can easyly have millions of elements in your listview.